# Using c# Method "in" parameter-modifier for Span<T> and ReadOnlySpan<T>

Tags: c#, memory, allocation

For using the "in" parameter-modifier, the type T must be a readonly struct.
More infomation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-parameter-modifier.

`Span<T>` and `ReadOnlySpan<T>` fulfill these criteria.

Here is the typical usage of the `in` parameter-modifier:

```
void CallerMethod(in Span<decimal> numbers)
{
      Span<decimal> numbers = stackalloc decimal[2]{5,6}; 
      Method1(in numbers);
}

void Method1(in Span<decimal> numbers)
{
      //codes lines here
}
```

But because `Span<T>` and `ReadOnlySpan<T>` are very special (collections!), am a bit confused. So here is my question: **can `in` be used for `Span<T>` and `ReadOnlySpan<T>` without any drawback?**

Comment: Your `CallerMethod` does not compile.

Comment: _"For using the "in" parameter-modifier, the type T must be a readonly struct. More infomation"_ - where it is written directly? You can use non-readonly `struct`'s as `in` parameters ([see](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLAChUwCwAICyBTYACwHsATACjADssANLADwEoBvVLDrAei8YDoAklgC8WBAG5uvUsTwBnLFWLAsAY2IBbAA6Q87Tgz4BNQSLGTUAX1So5wAE4BXVStqo2KTlhgBmLNRUhFiwAcwJJOXCsa09OXywjBKxgsOAIqJiY+AT3fQ54gKwg0KjItOirIA=)) Though you will not be able to modify them. But you will be able to modify reference types data the struct holds.

Comment: Also what drawbacks are you expecting?